# Readline "Miscellaneous Commands" not found

Tags: bash, readline

In trying to read in my `inputrc` file, I was reading https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands:

> re-read-init-file (C-x C-r)
>   Read in the contents of the inputrc file,
>   and incorporate any bindings or variable assignments found there.

Is `re-read-init-file` supposed to be a command I can execute? I am getting

```
$ re-read-init-file
-bash: re-read-init-file: command not found
```

I also got the same result with `abort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a command you can type on the command line.

You can *invoke* it through pressing <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>, as the manual shows (assuming the keybindings have not been changed).

The readline functions have names so that you are able to meaningfully bind keyboard shortcuts to them.  They are not commands in the sense that they are executables like `man`.

Comment: Thanks! Although, <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> didn't seem to do anything...the desired behavior in ~/.inputrc didn't take effect apparently. (Although <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> worked in generating an audible alert!) Would you happen to have any pointers on how I can further investigate this?

Comment: @flow2k That may also depend on what the changes to `.inputrc` you made.  Restarting the shell session will alse re-read the file.

Comment: Restarting the session helped, but the keystrokes are still not working (I reverted the .inputrc and tried several times). My ~/.inputrc is (in case you can spot anything) `"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward`.

Comment: What does `bind -P` show?

Comment: @ErikF It likely shows that the command is bound to the correct keys (as in my default setup).  However, this does not seem to work under all circumstances.

Comment: Are you running inside a virtual console (e.g. `tmux` or some graphical terminal) that might be stealing key combinations? Just guessing here.